# Создание сети в docker swarm

Tags: postgresql, spring, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

1. Имеется web приложение на java spring, которое подключается к postgres.
   строка подключения к базе `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres`
2. Имеется compose-file, который поднимает web приложение и базу.

```html
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
networks:
  - backend
image: postgres
ports: 
  - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  worker1:
networks:
  - backend
image: scripter51/worker
ports:
  - "8082:8082"
deploy:
  mode: replicated
  replicas: 2
  placement:
    constraints: [node.role == worker]

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

3. Публикую сервисы на машины командой

> docker stack deploy --compose-file copm.yml test

Проблема:
Если база данных и веб-приложение оказались на одной машине - всё работает, если на разных - то приложение не может найти БД по имени сервиса.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что swarm init был прописан на хосте, база поднималась на manager'е, а worker - на вируталке.